# Module-wide access control using auth extension

Tags: authentication, yii, access-control

I'm using the [auth](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/auth) extension for user access control. I have several modules with several controllers each. I'd like to control access on a modular basis. I tried adding operations as `moduleId.*` but I get a **401 Access denied** error on trying to access any controller in the module. My current solution is to add an operation for each controller as `moduleId.controllerId.*` and to combine these operations into a task for each module. Is there a better way of adding the module-wide access control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation for the module-wide control wasn't there. I altered the `/auth/filters/AuthFilter.php` file as follows:

```
protected function preFilter($filterChain)
{
    $itemName = '';
    $controller = $filterChain->controller;

    if (($module = $controller->getModule()) !== null){
        $itemName=str_replace('/','.',$module->getId()).'.';//for nested modules
        if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess($itemName . '*')) return true;//Added this
    }

    $itemName .= $controller->getId();
    ...
```

**Edit**

The latest code from the [Github repository](https://github.com/Crisu83/yii-auth) has this fix.